# When setting Laravel's DB, try to dynamically generate it

Tags: database, laravel, settings

The names of DB are board 1, board 2, board 3, board 4 to board 50. It takes time to create multiple connections each time, and I will have to do manual work every time I add it.

There is no solution for getting an error if you like the existing method in database.php?

```
for($board_no=1;$board_no<=50;$board_no++){
    'board'.$board_no => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'boardip',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'board'.$board_no,
        'username' => 'boardadmin',
        'password' => 'boardadminpassword',
        'unix_socket' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
       'prefix' => null,
       'engine' => null
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To create a config on the fly:**

Do this in your controller, it would just be appended to "database.connections" config.

```
Config::set('database.connections.key', array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'dbname',
    'username'  => 'dbuser',
    'password'  => 'dbpass',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
));
```

**Then you can connect to the db using:**

```
DB::connection('key');
```

Comment: Sorry,
I search for the number of board and DB that board belongs to
I try to use database.php for easy use.